# Go maps fails the concurency test

Tags: go, concurrency, locking, mutex, goroutine

When I run the following code:

```
import (
"log"
"sync"
"testing"
"time"
)
func TestConcurrency(t *testing.T) {
var mutex sync.RWMutex
dictionary := make(map[interface{}]interface{})
go func() {
    var value interface{}
    for {
        go func() {
            mutex.Lock()
            dictionary["Key"] = ""
            mutex.Unlock()
        }()

        go func() {
            mutex.RLock()
            value = dictionary["Key"]
            mutex.RUnlock()
        }()

    }
    log.Println(value)
}()
}
```

using :

```
go test -race fileName.go
```

It results in:

```
Found 1 data race(s)
```

How can I solve this?

I have many concurrent writes and reads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the error presented by the race detector, you would see that it reported concurrent writes on the `value = dictionary["Key"]` line, meaning the race being detected is on `value`, not `dictionary`.

You are concurrently accessing 2 variables, `dictionary` and `value`. You can't use the read lock to protect reads on the map, and writes to the `value` variable. You either need a second mutex, or you need to always use `mutex.Lock` to serialize access to both variables.

Answer (score 0):

This code will work correctly:

```
    go func() {
        mutex.Lock()
        value = dictionary["Key"]
        mutex.Unlock()
    }()
```

It protects the variable *value* from concurrent write.